# Remove GRUB cursor (before kernel)

Tags: assembly, bootloader, archlinux, grub2

I am trying to remove cursor that appears even before Boot menu and kernel (I am using GRUB2). I can remove `"GRUB loading"` and `"Welcome"` messages but the cursor still remains. I tried modifying registers `(AH, CH)` with `INT 10H` routine in `grub-core/boot/i386/pc/boot.S` but that didn't work out. Does anyone know if I am on the right tracks? Can someone give me additional help?

Comment: Are you asking how to stop the cursor being displayed on screen by changing the source code to GRUB and rebuilding it to create your own version of the bootloader?

Comment: Change the video mode to a graphics mode.  Voila, no cursor.

Comment: @RossRidge Yes.

Comment: From [here](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0086.htm), it seems like `cx = 2007h`, `ah = 01h` should work. (If it doesn't, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H) suggests `cx = 0706h`.)

Comment: The standard trick is just to set the cursor's column/row to something that is off the screen. That's usually easier, faster, and more reliable than changing to graphics mode, unless you actually *want* to be in graphics mode. This doesn't require a recompile of GRUB, either.

Comment: @CodyGray How would I do that? I have not seen any option for that.

Comment: `int 10h`, function 02h (set cursor position). Docs [here](http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0117.HTM).

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you a lot. But recompiling is still required?

Comment: You should be able to do this from your own code. Or perhaps I misunderstood when exactly you are trying to hide the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548277/how-to-hide-blinking-text-cursor-in-grub-boot. All you have to do is add the parameter `vt.global_cursor_default=0` in this line in /etc/default/grub:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=

... Then update grub